# Spring MVC :- How do i get the uploaded image to display on jsp page as soon as the user selects the image.I am using Spring Framwework here

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have uploaded the file to server but how do i get the image to display in jsp page...what steps do i need to follow?I guess i will need the path of the server location...but how do i get the path or is there a better way?

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addWebAchievement",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addAchievement(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image,@RequestParam("title")String title,@RequestParam("note")String note,
        Map<String,Object>m,@ModelAttribute("classObject") Clazz c ){
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    CustomUser user=null;
    if (principal instanceof CustomUser) {
    user = ((CustomUser)principal);
    }
    String username=user.getUsername();

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    String imageName1=image.getOriginalFilename();
    if (!image.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = image.getBytes();
            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "imageFiles");
            System.out.println(dir);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + imageName1);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

        }catch(Exception e){}
        }
```

addAchievement.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function readURL(input) {
                    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#userPhoto')
                          .attr('src', "<c:url value="e.target.result"/>")
                          .width(435)
                         .height(219);
                    };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                    }
            }
</script>



 <img class="activator" src="<c:url value="/resources/image/user-bg.jpg" />" id="userPhoto" alt="user bg" id="default_image">
```

Comment: Your subject says "How do i get the image to display on jsp page as soon as the user selects the image", you can do it by javascript actually which will work for almost all major browser.  You need to change your subject if i need to go through your description of the problem and source code. As two cases are different.

Comment: @ Maverick_Mrt Hello thanks for your response.. will I have to get the server path location so that i can pass it to my jsp... I will have to call the controller method through ajax I guess.I m confused actually ...

Answer (score 0):

to preview image when uploading image you can ahieve it by java script

```
<img src="images/<%=imageName%>" width="300px" height="150px" name="blogimage" id="imgprvw"/><input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="blogimage" onchange="showimagepreview(this)">
```

java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showimagepreview(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var filerdr = new FileReader();
filerdr.onload = function(e) {
$('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
</script>
```

and to diplay image that is already uploaded no need to pass any server location you can directly use path like

```
<img src="images/<%=imageName%>" width="300px" height="150px" />
```

here i am assuming that root folder for is images.you can user folder name

Comment: @ Srinivas Gadilli i have updated the post i tried the above js code it works in html page but dosent in jsp ... i have my spring tags in jsp ... how can i make this work

Comment: Are you calling java script function onchange="showimagepreview(this) or not?
and eventhough you are using spring tags in your jsp no need to give src like  $('#userPhoto')
                          .attr('src', "<c:url value="e.target.result"/>")
you can use $('#userPhoto')
                          .attr('src', e.target.result)

Comment: @ Srinivas Gadilli no i have done nothing like calling javascript function onchange="showimagepreview(this)" i am a novice... can u help

Comment: are you observed my code in answer or not 

<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="blogimage" onchange="showimagepreview(this)">

why you are not calling java script function ??